# grep for words of no more than a certain length

Tags: grep, regular-expression

I'm looking for a way to grep things like: `i log for E M, i 1 f x i 0, I xi 1, 3 1,.` simply based on number of characters.

Nothing in that hypothetical output is longer than three characters. This hypothetical one-liner would look something like, `grep -v [:alnum:] > {3}`. (Except I just don't know how to write that in grep syntax.)

Comment: Do you want to match characters like `,` and `.` as part of a word?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

```
grep -o -w '\w\{1,3\}' data
```

Options are:

- `-o` (a GNU extension) prints only matched words
- `-w` (an extension from BSD, but now widely supported) matches only whole words.

It matches only words (in grep, `\w` (a GNU extension) short for standard `[[:alnum:]_]` (same as `[A-Za-z0-9_]` in the C locale)) of length from 1 to 3 (specified by `{1,3}`)

Comment: thanks. the basic syntax of your answer is what i needed, and i ended up just using grep '\w\{3}' data and the same command with grep -v..

Comment: I had to use `egrep` on my side